# Django queryset use once

Tags: django

Sorry but I dont know what title I should give this question(Suggestion?)

I have the follwowing model:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    summer = models.CharField()
    winter = models.CharField()
    #other fields
```

and the following view:

```
def get_stuff(request, type, id):
    if type == 'summer':
        qs = Stuff.objects.filter(summer=id)
    if type == 'winter':
        qs = Stuff.objects.filter(winter=id)
    return qs
```

How can I use the query just once since I know what field to look in? Like this:

```
Stuff.objects.filter(type=id) #type = summer or winter field
```

Example:

```
type='summer'
id=1
Stuff.objects.filter(type=id) => Stuff.objects.filter(summer=id)

type='winter'
id=1
Stuff.objects.filter(type=id) => Stuff.objects.filter(winter=id)
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking here, What do you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not really saving very much, but I guess you want this:

```
qs = Stuff.objects.filter(**{type: id})
```

Comment: Cool Thnx! For me it's not about saving much or little, it's just about saving.